# HTML Submit Button, different value to post data

Tags: php, html, css, post, submit

I need the button text displayed to be different from the sent form value.

Is there a way to achieve this using CSS|HTML|PHP? Here's my pseudo.

```
<form  method='post' action='index.php'>
  <input type="submit" value="name1" name="remove">Remove 1</input>
  <input type="submit" value="name2" name="remove">Remove 2</input>
  <input type="submit" value="name3" name="remove">Remove 3</input>
</form>

<?php
  #Pressing Remove 1 will print "name1", Remove 2 will print "name2", etc.
  if(isset($_POST['remove']))
  {
      $_gone = $_POST['remove'];
      print $_gone
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `button` element (which can have child nodes), not an `input` element (which cannot).

```
<button type="submit" value="name1" name="remove">Remove 1</button>
```

Note that [old IE has limitations here](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/forms/multiple-submit-buttons.html).

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much! Exactly what I was after.